# Does android:minEms support for all languages (e.g. Chinese, Arabic)?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, localization

I know that one ems is typically equal to the size of 'M' character which is the longest character in English.

However, for other languages like Chinese or Arabic. Does it work the same way? (represent the longest character of that language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does provide support for more languages, android handles localization very well. In most modern typefaces an M is actually less than one em. According to the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aminEms) you can change the ems with the method setMinEms(int). If you would like to read more about Ems, try [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_%28typography%29).

To answer the second question, I will quote from the wiki. "Thus, em generally means the point size of the font in question, which is the same as the height of the metal body a font was cast on." The size of the characters will not exceed the em.